# How to update the version from File1 to File2 without changing the ID of File1?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I've been thinking this through for a while and I could not solved it, so I came here to ask for your help.

I'm creating an app based on Google Script.
I have 2 PDF files stored in Google Drive: File1 and File2.

I want to update the version of File1 by File2 without changing the ID of File1.

Is it possible to do this using Google Script Drive API v2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable the Advanced Drive API service in your Google Apps Script project and then use this snippet to update the content of an existing file in Google Drive.

```
  Drive.Files.update(
    {
      title: "file 1.pdf",
      mimeType: "application/pdf"
    },
    "id of file 1",
    DriveApp.getFileById("id of file 2").getBlob()
  )
```

Comment: Worked very well. Thank you so much.